# Node express Как отправить на страницу данные из разных моделей БД?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Мне необходимо составить таблицу с данными из нескольких коллекций, как можно отправить несколько коллекций на страницу?
Вот такой вариант разумеется не работает, но как правильно переписать я не понимаю.

```
app.get('/admin_bsk', (req, res) =>  {
  Client.find({}).then(clients => res.render('admin_bsk', {clients: clients}));
  Basket.find({}).then(baskets => res.render('admin_bsk', {baskets: baskets}));
  Mobile.find({}).then(mobiles => res.render('admin_bsk', {mobiles: mobiles}));
});
```

Comment: Нужна переменная, в которую будет сохранятся результат каждого запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через then.catch:

```
Client.find({}).then(clients => {
  Basket.find({}).then(baskets => {
     Mobile.find({}).then(mobiles => {
         res.render('admin_bsk', {mobiles: mobiles, baskets: baskets, mobiles: mobiles});
      })
   })
})
```

Через async/await:

```
app.get('/admin_bsk', async (req, res) =>  {
   try {
      client = await Client.find({});
      baskets = await Basket.find({});
      mobile = await Mobile.find({});
      await res.render('admin_bsk', {mobiles: mobiles, baskets: baskets, mobiles: mobiles}));
   } catch(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
   }
});
```